# Excel 2003 in Windows 10 - single instance/dde?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

I'm running Windows 10 and Excel 2003 (it runs much faster than newer versions of excel).

The problem is that I generally prefer most files to open in the same instance of excel.

Is there any way to accomplish this other than manually opening each file from excel itself?

I've tried toggling a number of things (command line tweaks with /e %1 and dde messages and other options inside of excel itself to no avail...)

I've tried replicating the "action" for "open" with fileTypesMan from my windows 7 build which works fine but that didn't help leading me to believe this is some idiosyncratic windows 10 behavior, i.e., https://i.postimg.cc/C1TcqnTb/Clipboard-Image-1.png

it would seem as though Win 10 is ignoring the DDE section of the action from my attempts at manipulating those options

perhaps this is informative re: windows disabling DDE?
https://office-watch.com/2017/dde-finally-dead-took-microsoft-long/
I tried adding registry keys as per the above but haven't tried rebooting just yet

Thanks

Comment: for the poor soul to look at this post in the future, I gave up on this and just used excel 2010 as that seems to be the least obnoxious "modern" version of excel that exists

Answer (score 0):

From  https://smallbusiness.chron.com/open-second-instance-ms-excel-new-window-64110.html

Quote "Open your first instance of Excel, and then right-click the Excel tile on the Start screen. Hold down the "Alt" key and click "Open New Window" on the Start screen taskbar. Continue holding down the "Alt" key until you see a prompt asking you if you want to start a new instance of Excel"

Excel 2003 is not fully compatible with Windows 10 so the above may or may not work

Comment: sorry, I'm looking to keep opening files in the same instance, not a new instance every time :(

Comment: I understand, looked hard and see nothing that will do this in Windows 10. Excel 2003 is 17 years old and not being developed.

Comment: Thanks for trying - even with that annoyance, it's still better than using terrible modern excel - I suspect that I might be able to make a workaround myself for this issue using autohotkey

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Did so many searches and nothing worked. Finally - I recalled messing it up when I first installed Excel 2003.

The fix?
Right click an Excel file in Windows Explorer and re-select the default program. (Open with --> Choose Default Program...).

Fixed! This was on a previous page may be it is working for you as well. To make Excel 2003 the default you can first fire up excel 2003 and then from the menu Help click on Analyse and repair or something like that because i have a dutch Excel. Make sure that when it starts that it loads excel 2003. If it starts another version stop the proces and it will continue with the right version. After it is ready you can do the fix above. It worked with me with WIN7 64 bit.
Good luck from the Netherlands

Comment: yeah, excel 2003 worked fine in win7 64 bit, the issue was with win 10 - fwiw, I just gave up and use excel 2010 as my version which is good enough I suppose though clearly less well written than 2003 in most respects